# ASP.NET controls C#

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get value from the databse and assign it to the label using the below line:

```
lblQuestion.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Question"].ToString();
```

but it assigns as label.

```
          if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                lblQuestion.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Question"].ToString(); ;
            }
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "but it assigns as label". Could you clarify that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED - Deleted my last info now that you have included the code....

Have you stepped through your code to see if any data is returning?

AKA - is `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0` ?

You are also doing `!Page.IsPostBack`.  This will only call the code and load your labels if it's on the first load.... What about subsequent loads?  The labels will return back to whatever they defaulted to in the designer.....

Comment: ToString() doesn't return the ColumnName property of the column as `.Rows[0]["Question"]` uses indexers to get the value of the Question column for the first record in the table.

Answer (score 1):

I've put together a test-case in a web app as follows:

ASPX Code-behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ds = new DataSet();
        var table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Question", typeof(string));
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "This is the question" });

        ds.Tables.Add(table);

        lblQuestion.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Question"].ToString();
    }
}
```

ASPX Page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQuestion"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
```

This renders out correctly as:

```
<div>
    <span id="lblQuestion">This is the question</span>
</div>
```

Are you sure you've shown us the code that's actually running?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (Request.QueryString["QID"] != null)
        //{
        //    Response.Write(Request.QueryString["QID"].ToString()); 
        //}
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["QID"]);
            // Response.Write(i);
            eTutorService ServiceProvider = new eTutorService();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = ServiceProvider.GetQuestionView(i);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                lblQuestion.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Question"].ToString(); ;
                lblOption1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Option1"].ToString();
                lblOption2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Option2"].ToString();
                lblOption3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Option3"].ToString();
                lblOption4.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Option4"].ToString();
                lblCorrectOption.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CorrectAnswer"].ToString();
                lblPaper.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["subject"].ToString();
                lblDifficultyLevel.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LEVEL_NAME"].ToString();
                lblquestionOrder.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["QuestionOrder"].ToString();
            }
        }


      }
```

Its just put **label** rather than putting database value to the label

Comment: Next time just put the code in your initial question instead of adding as an answer.... :-)